# player settings no load

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have an app built in Unity 5.4.1f1 on iOS platform, now I have Unity 5.6.3p4 and I want to update my app. I open the project and it appears to me that there is no Unity Ads and above it appears that the app is from iOS, but if I see Build Settings it appears that the app is' Standalone', before this change to iOS and when I see' Player Settings' I only see the title of' Resolution and presentation'. Faced with this I can not configure to have the project for Xcode.

What should I do? I need to update my app, please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQXkP.png)

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed unity setup for ios ?

Comment: Hi, I got it installed. I already found the problem, it happens that in the project was the Facebook SDK as plugin, before opening the project with Unity I deleted this folder, several errors jumped due to the lack of SDK but I could see the Player Settings. Thank you for your interest in helping.